# Could not able to access CELL_TYPE_STRING variable from XSSFCell

Tags: guidewire, gosu

I am trying to set cell type value by passing XSSFCell.CELL_TYPE_STRING. But it is throwing error "No static property descriptor found for property, CELL_TYPE_STRING"

cell.setCellType(XSSFCell.CELL_TYPE_STRING)

Answer (score 0):

first check your imports, XSSFCell class supposed to belong to

> package org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel;

maybe there is smth wrong with imports

also you can try

> Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING

- its more generic, since `.setCellType` expekts int as an argument should be no difference

Comment: Yes I have imported all the relevant jars. The variables declared as private in XSSFCell class and it is taking from poi-ooxml-4.1.2.jar. hence it could not able to access.  " private static final java.lang.String FALSE_AS_STRING = "0";
    private static final java.lang.String TRUE_AS_STRING = "1"; " . Previousl;y it was working fine in guidewire version 8 and it was public variable. Now in V10, we are facing this issue.